# swift infinite scrolling for loading previous chat history

Tags: ios, swift

As a iOS developer I need to fetch my chat messages seamlessly in a chat room using Swift 5.2

When it comes to implementation, I apply loading previous messages on cellForItemAt. This makes user scroll to edges for a few times to fetch my stuffs.

Would you please tell me the better way to fetch my previous messages seamlessly ?

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
...

    let itemsCount = Array(0..<messageCollectionView.numberOfSections)
        .map { messageCollectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: $0) }
        .reduce(0, +)
        
        if itemsCount > 9 {
            if messageCollectionView.isFirstItemFullyVisible {
                self.viewModel.loadMessages(.next , targetIndex: indexPath.item)
            }else if messageCollectionView.isLastItemFullyVisible {
                self.viewModel.loadMessages(.previous , targetIndex: indexPath.item)
            }
        }

        
        
        return itemCell
    }
```

Previous method :

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        var contentInset = scrollView.contentInset
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            contentInset = scrollView.adjustedContentInset
        }
        
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y <= -contentInset.top {
            viewModel.loadMessages(.previous)
        } else if scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.height <= scrollView.contentOffset.y {
            viewModel.loadMessages(.next)
        }
    }
```

\

Revised   :

This is hard to triggered Loading Previous but east to call Loading Next. I need the opposite

```
   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView == messageCollectionView {
            let contentInset = scrollView.adjustedContentInset
            if scrollView.contentOffset.y <= -contentInset.top && !isLoading {
                self.loadMoreData(state: "Loading Previous")
            } else if (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.height <= scrollView.contentOffset.y)   && !isLoading {
                self.loadMoreData(state: "Loading Next")
            }
  
        }
    }
    
    func loadMoreData( state : String  ) {
        if !self.isLoading {
            self.isLoading = true
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                // Fake background loading task for 2 seconds
                sleep(2)
                // Download more data here
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.showToast(message: state)
                    self.isLoading = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use scroll offset to decide when I should fire a new load request to have seamlessly scrolling experience. For example, you may want to fire a load more request whenever the distance from your current scroll position to edges reaches a distance equal `k * SCREEN_HEIGHT`. You should adjust the `k` to meet your need.

This is a very simple implemetation of the idea:

```
let fireRequestDistance = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
let numberOfItemsPerRequest = 50

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var items: [Int] = Array(0...100)
    
    var isLoadingNext: Bool = false
    var isLoadingPrev: Bool = false
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        tableView.reloadData()
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: items.count / 2, section: 0), at: .middle, animated: false)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        items.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(items[indexPath.row])"
        return cell
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if !isLoadingNext, scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.bounds.height > scrollView.contentSize.height - fireRequestDistance {
            isLoadingNext = true
            print("Loading next")
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false) { _ in
                let max = self.items.last!
                let newItems = Array((max + 1)...(max + numberOfItemsPerRequest))
                let indexPaths = (self.items.count..<(self.items.count + numberOfItemsPerRequest)).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
                self.items += newItems
                self.tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .none)
                self.isLoadingNext = false
            }
        }
        
        if !isLoadingPrev, scrollView.contentOffset.y < fireRequestDistance {
            isLoadingPrev = true
            print("Loading prev")
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false) { _ in
                let min = self.items.first!
                let newItems = Array((min - numberOfItemsPerRequest)..<min)
                let indexPaths = (0..<numberOfItemsPerRequest).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
                self.items = newItems + self.items
                self.tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .none)
                self.isLoadingPrev = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to the method scrollViewDidScroll to detect ? 

I have tried that method on my edit code but the scrolling response is too fast for collection view to handle data and  list

Comment: `but the scrolling response is too fast` What does this mean?

Comment: It means triggering the ""Loading previous too hard" please help me see see the revised method

Comment: @RajuyourPepe Checkout my updated answer to get the idea.